# Display legends for particular worksheet when switching between plots in tableau dashboard using parameters

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard

I am trying to develop a dashboard which will have different level of detail depending upon the user input. I have two maps, one showing data to the granularity of county and another one by zip codes. I am able to toggle between the graphs but the legend do not appear to toggle and remain on the screen. The link to the dashboard: https://public.tableau.com/profile/rohan.verma#!/vizhome/Zip-County/Dashboard3?publish=yes

Any help to display the legend for only the view would be appreciated. I am also open to suggestions on doing this in a different way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drilling down through different geographic level of details is not been fully developed well by tableau as a feature. I like the way that you've implemented it within your workbook. Feel free to upvote this [idea](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/4005) on the Tableau forums.

Check out this thread on the Tableau forums for an idea to hide the legend
https://community.tableau.com/thread/221281 (Amit Narkar's post)

https://community.tableau.com/thread/149536 (Another good forum post)

Essentially you would create a blank sheet triggered by the parameter which would hide the legend.